# Explained variance from scikit-learn MDS

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to calculate the explained variance (eigenvalues) from scikit learn's MDS? I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112853/how-to-obtain-the-eigenvalues-after-performing-multidimensional-scaling), but I think scikit learn's MDS is a "non-classical" form of MDS, so I'm guessing it wouldn't work? Is there a way to compute the explained variance from running scikit learn's implementation of MDS?

Also, if I'm using a precomputed dissimilarity matrix for scikit learn's MDS, is it then running classical MDS? Based on the code it seems like it's still running the SMACOF algorithm regardless (rather than eigendecomposition)?